# Angular transcluded directive with two-way binding to controller not updating

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

I am using this https://github.com/blackgate/bg-splitter for creating horizontal and vertical pane splitters. (The full code is in the plunkr I have created)

Since I started using it, I have an issue with the two-way binding of a controller and directive.

The directive has two variables, listData and the selectedOption:

```
template: '<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="l.name for l in listData" class="form-control"></select>',
    scope: {
        listData: "=",
        selectedOption: "="
    },
```

The controller has these variables and has a watch function to watch for changes:

```
$scope.listdata = [{id : 1, name : "listitem1"},{id : 2, name : "listitem2"},{id : 3, name : "listitem3"}];

$scope.selectedOption = null;

$scope.$watch('selectedOption', function() {
        console.log('updating selected choice');
        console.log($scope.selectedOption);
}, true);
```

And the directive is being used like:

```
<dropdown list-data="listdata" selected-option="listItem"></dropdown>
```

Without the paneSplitter the dropdown is working. For some reason, when the bound variable is updated in the dropdown directive, it doesn't get updated in the controller. This is probably a scope issue, but I can't seem to figure it out myself. Any help is greatly appreciated. Please see the following plunkr with the full code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UnJaPV8LYm3unILEU3Lq

Comment: This sounds like a problem with prototypical inheritance, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/957731

Comment: Hmm. But the transcluded directive and the dropdown directive both have an isolated scope with the controllers scope as parent right? Let me see if I can test this.

Comment: I tried to test it in your plunker but there was a lot of code and I didn't have a lot of patience, so it might be another issue. Still worth looking into I think. That linked answer is a very good read regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the famous quote: "If you are not using a .(dot) in your models you are doing it wrong?"
If you change the watch to this:

```
$scope.$watch('data.listItem', function() {
        console.log('updating selected choice');
        console.log($scope.data.listItem);
}, true);
```

and in change the Html to this

```
<dropdown list-data="listdata" selected-option="data.listItem"></dropdown>
```

Here a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F5jv9JYxTd4y89Qwat49?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome. I just watched the video where this quote comes from, and I don't think I will ever forget it ;). Guess after learning a lot of new stuff, it is always wise to go back to the basics at one point. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  This solved my issue as well.  Does it seem odd to anyone that we need to add items as nested objects?